# Windows Phone 8 Text Selection options

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, textselection

Good day, I'm trying to develop and app that adds a new option to the "text selection" menu on windows phone 8, right next to the "Copy" option normally displayed hovering above the selected text. This button is meant to simply execute an action over the selection that is specified by the user on another page, but should be available through the entire system, every time this menu is called by selecting text. What I need to know is: How is this menu, or element of the OS, refereed to? Can it be accessed? Can It be modified or customized?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access or modify this because this is built into the system keyboard.

But you could create a popup-like control and listen for the `Holding` event on your `TextBox` which then displays the popup. I think this would be very difficult to accomplish because the system copy option would be displayed too and you can't disable this. One thing you can try is to position your popup right next to the system one, but you would need to check whether the system copy option is displayed always on the same position relative to the selected text.